# Create shortcut to restart a service on another machine

Tags: windows, service, batch-file, shortcut

We have a server that is on the same LAN as my work computer.  I know you can use "net stop" and "net start" in a batch file to restart a service *on the local machine*, but is it possible to do that for a remote machine?

I know you can use \computer to browse a networked machine, for example, so is there some syntax that would be something like \computer net stop service or so on?

Right now I have to Remote Desktop into the machine, restart the service, then log off, which is a hassle.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266389/simplest-way-to-restart-service-on-a-remote-computer

Answer (score 1):

Create a Desktop shortcut
in the cmd to run enter :

```
sc \\server stop service
```

sc is the service management tool
server is your remote server name or IP
and finally service is the name of the service you target

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to use runas.exe to do this? I have to run it as a network admin account, and my regular workstation is not running as that.  For things such as SQL Server Management, I can make a runas shortcut, but I keep getting the help text instead of any action when I try the command.  I'm using:
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:[user] "sc.exe \\[server] stop "[service name]""

Comment: I figured it out - for anyone else wondering: you can use this command:
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:[domain\user]  "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Test.bat"

Where your batch file with the sc \\server stop service is in C:\Test.bat. (You can move that around obviously)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - for anyone else wondering: you can use this command:

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:[domain\user] "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Test.bat" Where your batch file with the sc \server stop service is in C:\Test.bat. (You can move that around obviously)